# In java, dynamic allocation

Tags: java, c, compilation, jvm

In C the compiler allocates the memory during compilation, but in Java the JVM allocates memory during runtime. So when the C compiler allocates memory after the compilation the ram is cleared, but how is the data stored during runtime?

Comment: The compiler compiles the code. At runtime memory is either on the stack or the free store depending

Comment: You wrote the answer yourself, _JVM handles these things_.

Comment: Thats the beauty of Java... It does it for you.

Comment: ‘*In C compiler allocates the memory*’ Nope. What gave you that idea?!

Comment: Hint: step back and do a bit more reading about these concepts. And maybe, question the sources you were relying on so far. Who told you that compiler "allocate" memory?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of misconceptions here:

> So when compiler allocates the memory after compilation the ram is cleared

Compilers don't allocate memory for the program; the memory is allocated when the program starts.  Basically the compiler just tells the JVM how to allocate memory for said program when it runs.

> then how the data is stored during run time?

The data is stored within the JVM interpreter, which is itself a program.  It has a place to store data for memory allocated by your program (not the compiler).

Answer (score 3):

A compiler cannot allocate memory -- of course it cannot. It depends on the runtime environment. For one, nothing guarantees that the machine the code is compiled on is the machine on which the code will actually run.

The main difference between C and Java in this regard is that C requires that you manage your memory {de,}allocations; Java has no such problem, although it does come with a few drawbacks. Understand that among other things, deallocation is automatic in Java -- *although not under your control*.

Basically, in C, if you can't `malloc()`, you get a `NULL`, therefore you "only" need to check for that and act accordingly; in Java, you get an `OutOfMemoryError` which is hard to recover from.

Those are two very different approaches, and for ease of use, and for better or for worse, more and more languages today go "the Java way" instead of "the C way".

But in any case, this has nothing to do with the compiler at all.